# FastAPI/Celery - Running 2 tasks in parallel not working

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have been trying to launch a celery worker to execute 2 tasks :
The first task :

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def listen_for_new_row(self):
    print("listen_for_new_row task started")
    with db as conn:
        conn.set_isolation_level(0)
        while True:
            with conn.cursor() as cur: # The use of with statement automatically closes the cursor after each loop iteration
                cur.execute("LISTEN new_row_added")
                conn.poll()
                while conn.notifies:
                    notify = conn.notifies.pop()
                    if notify.channel == "new_row_added":
                        result = compute_waterflow_diff(self.request.id)
                        print("New row added!")
            
                self.update_state(state='PROGRESS')

                cur.execute("SELECT 1")  # Keep the connection active
                conn.commit()
```

The second task : (very simple just for testing purposes)

```
@app.task()
def compute_daily_et0(task_id):
    print("Computing Reference Évapotranspiration - ET0")
```

Here is the celery-beat schedule :

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'listen_for_new_row': {
        'task': 'celery_worker.listen_for_new_row',
        'schedule': 10.0,
    },
    'compute_daily_et0': {
        'task': 'celery_worker.compute_daily_et0',
        'schedule': 10.0,
    },
}
```

Here is the docker-compose :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data-local:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  iot_api_local:
    image: iot_api_local
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:7.0-bullseye
  
  celery_worker:
    container_name: celery_worker
    build: .
    command: celery -A celery_worker worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=debug
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    depends_on:
      - iot_api_local
      - redis
  
  flower:
    container_name: flower
    build: .
    command: celery -A celery_worker flower --port=5555
    ports:
      - 5556:5555
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    depends_on:
      - iot_api_local
      - redis
      - celery_worker
  
  celery_beat:
    container_name: celery_beat
    build: .
    command: celery -A celery_worker beat --loglevel=debug
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    depends_on:
      - celery_worker
      - redis

volumes:
  db-data-local:
```

The problem is :

1. If i comment out one of the celerybeat schedules, it works fine
2. When both celery beat schedules are working, it executes the task listen_for_new_row normally, but the compute_daily_et0 executes only once.

After analysing flower, I see that the listen_for_new_row task jammes up the compute_daily_et0 which stay reserved, and if i kill one task (listen_for_new_row) manually it executes compute_daily_et0 once and then it jammes up again.

How can I solve this to make sure both tasks are running ?

Thanks,

I tried multiple solution, with making task expire or revoke listen_for_new_row tasks after execution, but it didn't work.